# AngularJS Attribute directive receives string at compile time

Tags: angularjs

I have the following attribute directive:

```
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('IPSConsoleApp').directive('tabSwitch', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 100000,
            scope: false,
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                if (attr.tabSwitch) {
                    element.children().remove();
                    element.remove();
                }
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

which is used in the following way from my view:

```
<personal-details account="account" tab-switch="viewdetails"></personal-details>
```

`viewdetails` is a boolean value which is set to true or false onclick of another button.

What I am trying to do here is a directive instead of `ng-if` which deletes my element when `viewdetails` is true and doesn't create a new child scope.

However, when debugging, this is what I receive in `attr.tabSwitch`:

> "viewdetails"

Of course, I don't want the actual string. I want the actual boolean value. Can this happen? I've been researching all over and can't find a way to pass this boolean value.

Thanks a lot for any help!

**EDIT:** while I still did not find any solution to this question, I ended up using the link function and using `scope.$eval(attr.tabSwitch)` which evaluates the string to the corresponding boolean value. This is for people looking for a similar function.

Comment: If i have understood your question then here is a small tip. You can set viewdetails on click of button using ng-click and set a $scope.viewdetails to the required value in controller. Then you can access same in your tabSwitch directive. There is no need pass it with the directive.

Comment: @Navaneeth I don't think that it's that simple, not from the `compile` step. At that point she has no access to any `$scope`.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I was going to reply @DRobinson.. at compile I can't access any scope.. not even as a parameter according to documentation :( I saw suggestions of using $observe in link function... but I need to be at compile time to remove element and $observe is on $scope as well!

Comment: I think you might be out of luck, avoiding super hack workarounds. Out of curiosity, why does it need to be in compile? Also, why is `ngIf` forbidden (other than that being at `link` time itself).

Comment: ngIf is forbidden because it creates a new child scope for me and I have a lot of logic using $scope variables inside those directives. I tried using it and it broke my two-way binding. I was using compile because I wanted the element to be removed before it is added to the DOM tree. Do you know a way to receive the boolean value in link at least? maybe I can try? Thanks

Comment: Well since you're using `scope: false`, in the link function your `scope` variable should point to its parent scope automatically. If you're sure that the parent scope has the value that you're after, you can use `scope[attr.tabSwitch]` in the link function. That should work.

Comment: Yet I'm still confused about why `ngif` is breaking your two-way bindings. The fact that it creates a scope for itself shouldn't caused that, and I frequently two-way bind models through (sometimes even a few levels of) `ngIf`. If it's simple to create a JSFiddle or Plunker where an `ngIf` is blocking your two-way bindings it may be easier to find the problem. Otherwise, try the `link`.

Answer (score 0):

Try interpolating the value with `{{}}`

```
<personal-details account="account" tab-switch="{{viewdetails}}"></personal-details>
```

and then checking for "true" or "false".

Comment: I tried this.. the string simply becomes "{{viewdetails}}"